# Simple Search Form - Show ALL results

Tags: simple-search

I hope this is a really easy question. I'd like my simple search form to return ALL results, what should I enter in to the results parameter please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a high number like 9999. If you can guesstimate the maximum number of results then any figure higher than that would be fine.